# UIActivityViewController. How to customize it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I would like to create a `UIActivityViewController` in my iPad application but I can't find anything on Google because it's a new view implemented only in iOS 6.
`UIActivityView` is a view that appears when a user tap, for example, the Share button inside Photos App.
A set of activities is presented by an activity view controller (Send via email, Share on facebook, print ecc...).
Each activity is represented by an icon and a title that appears below the icon.
Now I would like to custom the items inside the view but I can't find how to do it?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to subclass `UIActivityViewController`. Instead, create your own [`UIActivity`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclasses, and then instantiate `UIActivityViewController` with an array of your activities using:

```
- (id)initWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems applicationActivities:(NSArray *)applicationActivities;
```

Comment: I don't want my own activity but the default ones except for some (I want Mail and print but don't share on Facebook)

Comment: @user1679847 As described in [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `UIActivityViewController` has a `excludedActivityTypes` property that you can set to prevent some activity types from appearing, so you should be able to exclude Facebook by including `UIActivityTypePostToFacebook` in that list.

Comment: And Do you know how can I make it appears in a popover controller? Just like Photos App does it!

Comment: If `activities` is your `UIActivityViewController`, then create a popover with that as its content view controller: `popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activities];` Then present it as usual. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

[REActivityViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REActivityViewController) is probably what you are looking for. It also allows customizations more than UIActivityViewController. Try it. :)