# UIActivityViewController, pinterest

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to add pinterest to the UIActivityViewController in iOS 6, I couldn;t find any documentation on it or on how to make custom addition to the UIActivityViewController for some social networking.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579805/uiactivityviewcontroller-how-to-customize-it)

There is no native support for Pinterest in `iOS 6`, but by utilizing a custom [UIActivity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you should be able to get the desired behavior with the [Pinterest iOS API](http://developers.pinterest.com/ios/).